# Could not Cast Value problems Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, authentication

I have an app where I ask the user to login first. After a successful login I want the username to follow to all the other view controllers in the app. I have tried declaring this as a public variable, but I am not sure how to do that properly (ie. it is not working in any instance) so I am now trying a prepareForSegue approach. However when I do i get a `"Could not cast value of type 'SwiftLoginScreen.LoginVC' (0x10cdd33a0) to 'SwiftLoginScreen.ActionVC' (0x10cdd3130). (lldb)"` - error.

I want to be able to call up the username from any and all view controllers in the app, but I am not able to solve this. I have the username from my HomeVC and I now want it to pass on to my ActionVC.

Home VC:

```
import UIKit

class HomeVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var usernameLabel : UILabel!
    var currentUser : NSString!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

        let prefs:NSUserDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        let isLoggedIn:Int = prefs.integerForKey("ISLOGGEDIN") as Int
        if (isLoggedIn != 1) {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_login", sender: self)
        } else {
            self.usernameLabel.text = prefs.valueForKey("USERNAME") as? String
            currentUser = prefs.valueForKey("USERNAME") as? String
        }
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {

        let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ActionVC
        destinationVC.operatingUser = self.currentUser;

    }

    @IBAction func gotoAction(sender : UIButton) {

        let appDomain = NSBundle.mainBundle().bundleIdentifier
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removePersistentDomainForName(appDomain!)

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("goto_action", sender: self)

    }

}
```

Action VC:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class ActionVC : UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate{

    @IBOutlet var usernameLable : UILabel!

    var operatingUser : NSString!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.usernameLable.text = operatingUser as? String

    }
```

Comment: In your prepareForSegue you don't check which segue you are operating on - it seems that the destination for the segue in question is a `LoginVC` instance, not an `ActionVC` instance, so the forced downcast fails

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, thats another view controller i have for the login process, however that should not be affected by the added code. how do i change my prepareFOrSegue statement then to only operate on the Action and Home VC?

Comment: You can check the identifier or the class type of `destinationViewControllee`

Comment: i thought i was? sorry - not following you. could you elaborate please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`prepareForSegue` will get called for all segues involving the View Controller.  In your case it is being called for a segue where the destination view controller is an instance of `LoginVC`, but you have a forced downcast (`as!`) to `ActionVC` - so you get an exception at runtime.

You can use an optional binding to make sure that you are handling the correct segue -

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {      

    if let destinationVC = segue.destinationViewController as? ActionVC {
        destinationVC.operatingUser = self.currentUser;
    }

}
```

Comment: works like a charm - excellent thank you! follow up question: since this method is declared as an override in my home controller can i call if from any subsequent view or do i have to declare this again? that is if i want to continue on from my action view with my username can is this included automatically in any and all segues after this?

Comment: You would typically implement `prepareForSegue` in each UIViewController subclass because you need to handle the specific segues

Comment: ok, had a feeling it would have to be done so. thank you for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem can be solved by adding
a username variable in AppDelegate class.

If you have a variable named userName
in AppDelegate you can access it anywhere in your app without passing it.

```
class AppDelegate
{
  var userName = "Admin"
}


let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
```

In your first controller you can set
the value:

```
appDelegate.userName = "Value"
```

and use the same to access it from
another controller:

```
let appDelegate = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate

appDelegate.userName
```

Comment: interesting - ill try this too. this would actually work better than passing it with a segue

Comment: I tried this but couldnt get it to work. Ill post a new question concerning this matter since the other answer solved this specific question.